# Determine if python is being run in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have a Python 3.2 program that runs like this:

```
import platform
sysname = platform.system()
sysver = platform.release()
print(sysname+" "+sysver)
```

And on windows it returns:

Windows 7

But on Ubuntu and others it returns:
Linux 3.0.0-13-generic

I need something like:

Ubuntu 11.10 or Mint 12

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.linux_distribution

Comment: Thanks, I really should read the docs more, ehh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`platform.dist`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/platform.html#platform.dist).

```
>>> platform.dist()
('Ubuntu', '11.10', 'oneiric')
```

Comment: platform.dist() is now out of date, we should be using platform.linux_distribution() (just read the docs, thanks to @Gazler)

Comment: @triunenature: No such deprecation warning exists in Python 3. http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/platform.html#platform.dist

Comment: Good to know :D  I really need to read those docs more carefully.

Comment: According to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.dist
Either `dist()` or `linux_distribution()` is deprecated since 3.5, and will be removed in 3.7.

Comment: @DmitryVolosnykh: That's nice of them to point to an alternative.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like `platform.dist()` and `platform.linux_distribution()` are [deprecated in Python 3.5 and will be removed in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.dist). The following works in Python 2/3

```
import platform
'ubuntu' in platform.version().lower()
```

Example return value

```
>>> platform.version()
'#45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 4 09:38:31 UTC 2022'
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning deprecation status

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 18.04 as well.

Comment: On my ubuntu 20.04 machine this value still doesn't contain ubuntu

Comment: @KeithSmiley I updated to work on Ubuntu 20, use platform.version() instead of platform.platform()

Answer (score 6):

The currently accepted answer uses a deprecated function. The proper way to do this as of Python 2.6 and later is:

```
import platform
print(platform.linux_distribution())
```

The documentation doesn't say if this function is available on non-Linux platforms, but on my local Windows desktop I get:

```
>>> import platform
>>> print(platform.linux_distribution())
('', '', '')
```

There's also this, to do something similar on Win32 machines:

```
>>> print(platform.win32_ver())
('post2008Server', '6.1.7601', 'SP1', 'Multiprocessor Free')
```

Comment: [This method is deprecated and scheduled for removal in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.dist).

Answer (score 0):

Many of the solutions do not work when executing inside a Container (The result is the host distro instead.)

Less elegant - but container friendly approach:

```
from typing import Dict

def parse_env_file(path: str) -> Dict[str, str]:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:                                               
        return dict(tuple(line.replace('\n', '').split('=')) for line in f.readlines() if not line.startswith('#'))

def is_ubuntu() -> bool:
    return "ubuntu" in parse_env_file("/etc/os-release")["NAME"].lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

With `platform` python module, I recommand `uname()` method, which returns a NamedTuple:

```py
import platform

print(platform.uname())
```

It returns something like:

> uname_result(system='...', node='...', release='...', version='...', machine='...', processor='...')

`version` element of tuple can be useful to have Ubuntu information.

Answer (score -1):

```
is_ubuntu = 'ubuntu' in os.getenv('DESKTOP_SESSION', 'unknown')
```

Picks up if you are runnning in Unity or Unity-2D if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: What if you are running on a ubuntu server setup without a desktop?

Comment: The idea wasn't looking for ubuntu, its for mapping which OS is being run.